# Retrieve values of an array of object Angular

Tags: angular

I'm trying to retrieve the values of dynamic inputs and to sum up them afterwards.

this is my html with the form and the stepper

```
 <form
  clrStepper
  clrForm
  #allocationForm="ngForm"
  (ngSubmit)="submit(allocationForm.value)"

>
  <clr-stepper-panel ngModelGroup="{{allocation.type}}"  *ngFor="let allocation of allocations; let last = last"  #{{allocation.type}}="ngModelGroup">
    <clr-step-title>{{allocation.type}} </clr-step-title>
    <clr-step-content *clrIfExpanded>
      <p  style=" margin-top: 24px">Der Gesamtbetrag muss 100% betragen.</p>
      <div class="clr-row">
        <div class="clr-col-7" style="margin-top: 24px;">
      <clr-input-container style="display: flex; flex-direction: row; min-height: 48px; margin-top: 8px;"  *ngFor="let sub of allocation.subtype; let i = index" >

        <label class="clr-col-4">{{sub.name}}</label>

        <input class=" clr-col-3" name="{{'value'+ i}}" clrInput [min]="0"  [max]="100"
               clrNumeric pattern="^[0-9][0-9]?$|^100$" required [(ngModel)]="sub.value" clrUnit="%"  value="{{sub.value}}"
               >
        <clr-control-error class="text-center" *clrIfError>0-100%</clr-control-error>

      </clr-input-container>
        </div>
        </div>
      <button clrStepButton="next" (click)="checkPercentage(allocationForm)" *ngIf="!last">WEITER</button>
      <button clrStepButton="submit" *ngIf="last">SPEICHERN UND BEENDEN</button>

    </clr-step-content>
  </clr-stepper-panel>
</form>
```

in my ts file

```
    allocationForm: NgForm;
  allocations = [
    {
      type: 'Department',
      subtype: [
        { name: 'AR', value: 0 },
        { name: 'SC ', value: 0 },
        { name: 'SCH ', value: 0 },
        { name: 'LAC ', value: 0 }
      ],
    },
    {
      type: 'Groups',
      subtype: [
        { name: 'LAC', value: 0 },
        { name: 'ME ', value: 0 },
        { name: 'RR ', value: 0 },
        { name: 'SP ', value: 0 }
      ],
    }
  { }...


 submit(allocationForm: {}) {
    console.log(' form submit', Object.values(allocationForm));

    for (let value of Object.values(allocationForm)) {
      console.log(value)
  }}

  checkPercentage(allocationForm: NgForm) {

    /*console.log(Object.values(allocationForm));


   const sum = Object.values(allocationForm).reduce((acc, cur) => acc + cur, 0);

    console.log(sum)*/
  }
```

[Here are the console logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOa21.png)

All the arrays are always empty exept for the last one, it doesnt save the others.
And if I write the code of the submit() into checkpercentage() it doesn't work at all.

So the problems are two:
1- All the arrays of the single step are not saved
2- I cannot use the sum function because  in "acc + cur"
Operator '+' cannot be applied to types 'unknown' and 'unknown'.

I'm here for any further question, thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this to work:

```
let singularPercentage = allocationForm?.value.Department

    const myArr: number[] = Object.values(singularPercentage);
    const sum = myArr.reduce((acc, cur) => acc + cur, 0);
    console.log(sum)
```

it does what I want, just the "Department" should be dynamic depending on the ngModelGroup that I have in HTML, but I couldnt make it till now

Answer (score 0):

I guess the issue is because you are not assigning it properly. Try using the parameter directly.

```
submit(allocationForm: any) {
console.log(' form submit', allocationForm);
```

// your another code

Comment: Nope, because it says that is not iterable like this

Comment: @FedericaLavigne Can you create stackblitz demo for this so I can help better

Comment: sorry it seems that it doesn't work there with the code that I have. 
I figure it out in the meanwhile that I just need this singularPercentage to be dynamic and it works:
 this.singularPercentage = allocationForm?.value.Department (or .Groups etc..) 
But I don't know how to change it dynamically